# Google Spreadsheet, SUM or MINUS of above cell in the column using ARRAYFORMULA in the first row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm learning to use array formulas and have been successful doing simple things like adding 2 columns together in a third column. For example, I can put `=arrayformula(B:B+C:C)` in D1 and it adds B and C for each row.

But now I have a situation where I want to subtract two numbers in the same column. I want to take the value of that column in the current row and subtract the previous row's value from it. Without array formulas this is simple: in O7 I put =N7-N6 and cop that down so O8 gets =N8-N7, etc. But that requires copying down every time - can I do the same thing with an array formula?

Basically, can I do something like `=arrayformula(B:B+(B-1):(B-1))` ?

Context: column N is a monthly account balance. I would like to calculate how much that balanced changed each month. So for row 7, =N7-N6 gives me that difference. But I'm changing the entire spreadsheet to array formulas so I can stop pasting all of the formulas and I'm stuck on this one since it's comparing the same column.

I'm trying to get everything into Row 1 so my values and calculations can start in Row 2. For example, here's one of my formulas in Row 1:

```
arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Total gross income",if(LEN(B:B),B:B+C:C,"")))
```

Unfortunately, in Column O (the one I asked about originally) if I do this:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Amount saved this month",if(row(A:A)>1,if(LEN(N:N),N2:N-N:N,""))))
```

Or this:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Amount saved this month",if(row(A:A)>1,if(LEN(N:N),offset(N:N,1,0)-N:N,""))))
```

Every row is off by 1 - the result that should go in Row 3 goes in Row 2, etc. And if I do this:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Amount saved this month",if(row(A:A)>1,if(LEN(N:N),N:N-offset(N:N,-1,0),""))))
```

Then it gives me an error because the offset function is trying to evaluate something out of range (possibly it starts with N1 and tries to grab a value 1 row above N1?)

Any advice on how to handle that out-of-range error?

Comment: If the main issue is with offsetting a full column, i.e. `N:N`, you can always put instead something like `N2:N999999`, does that suffice?

Answer (score 4):

I think the error is because of offset range N:N which starts from N1 and you are trying to shift it -1 or one cell up, which brings the formula out of sheet.

Try this formula instead:

`=arrayformula(
{"Amount saved this month";
if(LEN(N2:N),N2:N-offset(N2:N,-1,0),"")})`

---

It uses `{}` to make an array. See more info:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en

---

**Bonus.** There is no reason to check row number now.